# How can I extract a TestCaseID from JQL query in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jql

I have mentioned a node in jenkinspipeline as below

```
node {
  stage('JIRA') {
  
   def key = jiraJqlSearch jql:"project = MAV AND issueType = 'Test' AND Status ='Done'", site: 'JIRA'
   def text = key.data.toString()
   echo "Test Case ID-->${text}"
  }
}
```

I am getting bulk data as response

I want to extract only "test case Id" from the above bulk data

[JQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSOig.png)

[Jenkins Consle Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYZ2O.png)

Is there any way to get test case IDs from JIRA in jenkins pipeline ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
node {
  stage('JIRA') {
    def result = jiraJqlSearch jql:"project = MAV AND issueType = 'Test' AND Status ='Done'", site: 'JIRA'
    for (def issue in result.issues()) {
      echo "Test Case ID-->${issue.key}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No luck is there any other way to get the Test-Case-ID, is there any URL to get  knowledge on this